# JQuery Unused Variable Error

Tags: jquery, unused-variables

I have a script to populate data from database but the variable i'm trying to use  variable `selected` seems to not being used. What I mean by that is Netbeans is telling me that the variable is unused. Is there something wrong with the script?

```
function get_child_options(selected)
{
    if (typeof selected === 'undefined')
    {
        var selected = ' ';
    }

    var parentID = jQuery('#parent').val();

    jQuery.ajax(
    {
        url: '/MyProjectName/admin/parsers/child_categories.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:
        {
            parentID: parentID,
            selected: selected
        },
        success: function(data)
        {
            jQuery('#child').html(data);
        },
        error: function()
        {
            alert("Something went wrong with the child options.")
        },
    });
}

jQuery('select[name="parent"]').change(get_child_options);
```

Comment: `var selected` is outside the block scope. Move `var selected` before `if(typeof`

Comment: selected is already defined in the function params. remove the `var ` before it like @dxcorzo shows in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove your *selected* variable. You have a function parameter and a variable with the same name.

```
function get_child_options(selected)
{ 
     if(typeof selected === 'undefined')
     {
         selected = ' ';
     }

     var parentID = jQuery('#parent').val();
     jQuery.ajax(
     {
         url: '/MyProjectName/admin/parsers/child_categories.php',
         type: 'POST', 
         data: {'parentID': parentID, 'selected': selected}, 
         success: function(data)
         { 
             jQuery('#child').html(data); 
         },
         error: function()
         {
             alert("Something went wrong with the child options.")
         }
     }); 

     jQuery('select[name="parent"]').change(get_child_options);
}
```

Comment: Just tried your script and Netbeans is still telling me the variable selected is `unused`.

Comment: Check it again please